# How do I mock LocalDateTime() in Kotlin with Mockk

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mockk

I'm writing test for a UserService that creates an anonymous user, and part of that includes saving a timestamp at time of creation. The time seems to be mocked properly within the test function itself, but when a timestamp is added in the actual UserService, the real time is being returned.  How do I mock it properly?

the relevant UserService function is:

**UserService.kt**

```
fun createAnonymousUser(jwt: AuthenticationJsonWebToken): User {

    val user = User()

    user.anonUserId = jwt.name 
    user.createdAt = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)

    return userRepository.save(user)
}
```

**UserService.test.kt**

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
open class UserServiceTest {
    private val jwt = mockk<AuthenticationJsonWebToken>()
    private val userRepository = mockk<UserRepository>()
    private val authProperties = AllAuthProperties()
    private val fixedClock = mockk<LocalDateTime>()
    private val slotUser = slot<User>()

    @BeforeTest
    internal fun init() {
        clearAllMocks()
    }

    @Test
    fun getMe() {
        every { jwt.name } returns "anonymous|123"
        every { LocalDateTime.now() } returns LocalDateTime.MAX

        val userService = UserService(userRepository, authProperties)

        val user = User();
        user.anonUserId = jwt.name
        user.createdAt = LocalDateTime.now()

        every { userRepository.save(capture(slotUser)) } returns user
        val anonUser = userService.getMe(jwt)


        verify { userRepository.save(anonUser) }
        assertEquals(anonUser, user)
    }
}
```

I'm just not sure how to accomplish what I'm trying.

Comment: Why don't you replace `user.createdAt = LocalDateTime.now()` with simply   `user.createdAt = LocalDateTime.MAX `, using a mock for LocalDateTime adds nothing here.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had it mostly right; I just needed a slight tweak.

```
verify { userRepository.save(anonUser.capture) } 
assertEquals(anonUser, user)
```